# unable to share a proc between two classes

Tags: nim-lang

I am playing around with NIM and classes. Ima trying ti have one i it function for two classes, however it seems that this result in the initialization nit to be possible.
The code looks like this

```
type Attribute* = object
  field: float

type Attributes* = object
  all: Table[string, Attribute]

proc init* (self: var Attribute|Attributes, values: openarray[float]=[]) =
  if self is Attribute:
    #do something
  elif self is Attributes:
    self.all = initTable[string, Attribute]()
  else:
     #do something
```

The self.all assignment always return error, cannot assign self. This does not change even if the prod is generic or I write var | var.
What error am I making?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following syntax `Attribute|Attributes` defines a typeclass.

The nim manual states that "type classes are static constraints to be enforced at type instantiations. Type classes are not really types in themselves but are instead a system of providing generic "checks" that ultimately resolve to some singular type. Type classes do not allow for runtime type dynamism, unlike object variants or methods."

Procedures using typeclasses are implicitly generic. A call to a generic proc statically instantiates a specialized proc for each unique type.

Therefore, you must check what type your generic has resolved to at compile time.

Enough *word vomit*. Here's example code:

```
type
  First = object
    field: float
  Second = object
    field: float
    uniqueField: int

proc accept(something: var (First|Second)) =
  something.field = 1.0 # This is valid since field can be statically resolved with the
                        # generic constraints.
  # something.uniqueField = 1 # This is invalid. uniqueField can be statically
                              # resolved, but it is invalid for all instances of
                              # something.
  if something is Second:
    # something.uniqueField = 1 # Same as above.
                                # Looks valid, but if is a runtime check.
    discard

  when something is Second:
    something.uniqueField = 2
    # Now this is valid. uniqueField can be resolved statically and is valid for
    # the instance of something.

var (f, s) = (First(), Second())

accept f
echo f.field # == 1.0

accept s
echo s.field # == 1.0
echo s.uniqueField # == 2
```

Neat note: If you check out the generated c code you'll see that the instance of the accept proc for the `Second` type is the only function that has `something.uniqueField = 2` expression.

Comment: What was wrong in OP's example? Why writing a new example from scratch?
Why "word vomit" is in bold?

Comment: Edited. 1. Compile time vs run time check. 2. I expanded a bit on the capabilities of typeclasses using more general names. It's pretty much the same example. 3. I sometimes like to add **flair** to my posts to break up the monotony.

Answer (score -1):

Why does it not work for you? I've tried the example and it compiles fine for me with either 1.4.8 or 1.6.10:

```
import tables

type Attribute* = object
  field: float

type Attributes* = object
  all: Table[string, Attribute]

proc init* (self: var Attribute|Attributes, values: openarray[float]=[]) =
  if self is Attribute:
    discard
  elif self is Attributes:
    self.all = initTable[string, Attribute]()
  else:
    discard
```

Comment: I get the error that self.all cannot be assigned on 1.4.8. When I actually use the Init function